# Cancel "tcplistener" from backgroundworker's CancelAsync()

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, backgroundworker, tcplistener

I have a Windows form from which when a button is clicked an instance of `Backgroundworker` starts a `tcplistener` method in another class.

I would like to be able to cancel the `tcplistener` after it's started or while it's receiving\writing data to disk.

I have set the `backgroundworker` arguments to be available for the `tcplistener` class so that the `cancellationpending`argument can be used to cancel operations in the `tcplistener` class. 
The issue is that once the "tcplistener.server" is started, if the cancel button is clicked, the listener is not being stopped or terminated.

To achieve this I have put the `tcplistener` code in a `while (bgw.CancellationPending != true)` assuming if the argument is wrong the listening would be cancelled

Here is my back `groundworker` code:

```
    private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //private void startBtn_Click(BackgroundWorker bw, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bgw.IsBusy != true)
        {
            if (ipTxt.Text != "" && portTxt.Text != "" && dirTxt.Text != "" && bufferTxt.Text != "")
            {
                cancelBtn.Enabled = true;
                listenerLabel.Text = "...";
                resultLabel.Text = "...";
                netwrkLst.Enabled = false;
                ipTxt.Enabled = false;
                portTxt.Enabled = false;
                bufferTxt.Enabled = false;
                dirTxt.Enabled = false;
                brwsBtn.Enabled = false;
                startBtn.Enabled = false;
                this.bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fill in all fields first");
            }
        }
    }

    //This event handler cancels the backgroundworker
    private void cancelBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
        if (bgw.IsBusy == true)
        {
            // Cancel the asynchronous operation.
            this.bgw.CancelAsync();
            cancelBtn.Enabled = false;
            startBtn.Enabled = true;
            listenerLabel.Text = "Listening canceled.";
            resultLabel.Text = "...";
            netwrkLst.Enabled = true;
            ipTxt.Enabled = true;
            portTxt.Enabled = true;
            bufferTxt.Enabled = true;
            dirTxt.Enabled = true;
            brwsBtn.Enabled = true;                
        }
    }

    // This event handler is where the work is done. 
    private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.bgw.CancellationPending == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        listener.tcp(
        ipTxt.Text,
        portTxt.Text,
        dirTxt.Text,
        bufferTxt.Text, bgw, e);
    }

    // This event handler updates the progress. 
    private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        resultLabel.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
    }

    // This event handler deals with the results of the background operation. 
    private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Canceled!";
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Done!";
        }
    }
```

And here is my `tcplistener` code:

```
    namespace McServer
    {

    public class listener
    {

    // Raise the UpdateLabel event, passing "Outside" as
    // the message.

    public static event Action<string> UpdateLabel;
    public static event Action<string> UpdateLabel2;
    //public volatile bool shutdown = false;

    public static void tcp(string ip, string portID, string path, string buffer, BackgroundWorker bgw, DoWorkEventArgs ev)
    {
        //if (bgw.CancellationPending == true)
        //{
        //    ev.Cancel = true;
        //    return;
        //}
        //while (bgw.CancellationPending != true)
        //{

        TcpListener server = null;
        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd" + "_" + "HH-mm-ss");

        while (bgw.CancellationPending != true) try
            {
                // Set the TcpListener.
                Int32 port = Int32.Parse(portID);
                IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
                Int32 buff = Int32.Parse(buffer);
                // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
                server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

                // Start listening for client requests.

                // Buffer for reading data
                //Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1000 * 1024];
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[buff];

                server.Start();


                // Enter the listening loop.
                while (true)
                {
                    UpdateLabel("Waiting for a connection...");
                    // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                    // Can also also use server.AcceptSocket() here.

                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                    UpdateLabel("Connected...");
                    // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                    int i;
                    int j = 0;
                    int k = 0;
                    // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        j++;
                        k = k + i;
                        if (k >= 1024)
                        {
                            k = k / 1024;
                            UpdateLabel("Received:" + k + " MB");
                        }
                        if (k >= 1024 * 1000)
                        {
                            k = k / 1024 / 1024;
                            UpdateLabel("Received:" + k + " GB");
                        }
                        UpdateLabel("Received:" + k + " Bytes");

                        //write to file
                        using (FileStream stream2 = new FileStream(path + j + "_" + time + "_" + ".tcp", FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            stream2.Write(bytes, 0, i);
                            stream2.Close();
                        }
                        // Send back a response.
                        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    }
                    // Shutdown and end connection
                    client.Close();
                    UpdateLabel2("Connection closed by client...");
                }
            }

            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                UpdateLabel2("An error occured: SocketException:" + e);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Stop listening for new clients.
                server.Stop();
                UpdateLabel2("Listening stopped...");
            }
        //}

        {
            ev.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You need to be periodically checking for the cancellation flag **INSIDE** the `while (true)` block.

Comment: But I have the issue even before the `while (true)` at `server.Start();`. So basically if there is no connection received even if I check for cancellation inside `while (true)` the cancellation while listening is started doesn't work.

Comment: How does the code get **OUT** of the `while (true)` loop?  It is stuck in the inner loop as far as I can see.  Are you able to get more than one connection at a time with this code?...

Comment: Hi Idle_Mind and thanks for looking into this. I think you are right, it does get stuck in the `while (true)` loop. How do I get out while in this loop? May be I use `if` statement to check for cancellation but then what if the `tcplistener` server is started but no connection is received!!

Comment: Ok, I made the below changes after the `while (true)` and it seems to be cancelling the listener while server is started but no connection received. So far so good need to make more changes\tests when connection is accepted

Comment: `while (bgw.CancellationPending != true)
                        {
                            UpdateLabel("Waiting for a connection...");
                            // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                            // Can also also use server.AcceptSocket() here.
                        }
                        if (bgw.CancellationPending == true)
                        {
                            ev.Cancel = true;
                            return;
                        }`